# Alt + Left click doesn't do roll on selected bones

Tags: armature

I've been struggling with a problem. I Have a windows PC, and I've experimented on Blender 3.6 and 4.0. and for some reason when I've got two bones selected and I want to roll on the transform menu with alt pressed it doesn't work, I've tested in others PCs and it work, I've tried a check up online keyboard and mouse and it seams ok, I've switch the keyboard and it got the same problem. Does anyone knows what is missing in my PC????